# macOS: Sierra: git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81) : is this latest version?

Tags: git, macos-sierra

I have the Apple-shipped git version on my MacBook (running Sierra).

`git --version` gives me:

```
git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
```

Is this latest or do I need to download latest? On [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/), I see this:

```
Looking for the latest version? Download git-2.7.1-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg (25.2 MB)
```

and in the table below this link, i see that latest version seems to be: 
`git-2.10.1-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg` with update date of Oct 2016.

Comment: Git is pretty stable at this point. I'd just use the vendor-provided version unless you have a very specific reason to upgrade.

Comment: As a side note, you are probably fine using any of the above versions.

Comment: "Is this latest or do I need to download latest?" No and no.

Comment: Thank you - I'll just use the version already installed.